# How can I add an option element in this select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to add an `option` element to my `select` which has the value provided by the `#quantite` input. I want that when we click the button the `GetValues()` function adds the element. I tried this:

```
<input class="text" id="quantite" type="text" name="quantité" />
<select id="multiSelect" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="o4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="o5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="o6">Option 6</option>
</select>
<br />
<button id="btnGetValues" onclick="GetValues()">Get Values</button>
```

```js
function GetValues() {
    // Get select object
    var myList = document.getElementById("multiSelect");

    //Create array to store selected values
    var Selectedelement = $("#quantite").val() ;

    myList.add(Selectedelement);
}
}
```

I get an error in javascript in `mylist.add(Selectedelement);`

Comment: Try appendChild("<option value='abc'>abc</option>")

Comment: Where is `SelectedUsers` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns DOM element. You should use `jQuery` object. And you should also use `append` instead of `add` to add new element.  Try following.

```
function GetValues() {
     var myList = $("#multiSelect");
     var Selectedelement = $("#quantite").val();

     myList.append('<option value='+Selectedelement+'>'+ Selectedelement +'</option>');                
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't test this as it will just append the text value to a `select`, not a `option` element. Also, what is `SelectedUsers`?

Comment: You are right I've not tested this before. I've updated my answer. Thanks. +1 @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: How can i display in the element here <select id="multiSelect" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="o4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="o5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="o6">Option 6</option>
</select>                   after added

Comment: What did you mean? @rcode

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new `option` element and use `appendChild()` to add it to the `select`. Try this:

```
function GetValues() {
    var myList = document.getElementById("multiSelect");
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = document.getElementById('quantite').value;
    option.innerText = 'New Option';
    myList.appendChild(option);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/42rqe5r2/)

Or for a purely jQuery solution:

```
<button id="btnGetValues">Get Values</button>
```

```js
$('#btnGetValues').click(function() {
    $('#multiSelect').append('<option value="' + $('#quantite').val() + '">New option</option>');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/42rqe5r2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need yo append an option:

```
$("#multiSelect").append('<option value="anyValue"> '+$("#quantiCommande").val()+' </option>');
```

Comment: @rcode see updated answer.

Comment: how can i display the content when i select one of this list:<select id="multiSelect" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="o4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="o5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="o6">Option 6</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

I prefer plain javascript.

Look [this example](https://jsbin.com/weqivisemo/edit?html,js,output), I create node element throw [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) API and setting [OptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) attributes.